# Trying to call a shell script from an R script using system(). But the shell script is not found

Tags: r, shell, command-line

I am trying to call a shell script from an R script using R's `system()` function.

I am doing the following:

In my R script I call the `system()` function: `system(exe, intern = TRUE,wait = TRUE)`,
exe contains the necessary arguments for the shell script, starting with the file path from the R script directory to the shell script directory, to call the script.

This returns `sh: 1: 'file-path-to-shell-script': not found`

When I copy paste what is contained in exe, and run it directly in the command line, starting from the file location of the R script, it works perfectly.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using a *relative* path to your shell script. Execute `getwd()` within your script to make sure that your working directory corresponds to the directory that the script resides in. If your current working directory does not correpond to the location of your script you have a couple of options:

1. use `setwd()` to set your working directory to the correct location so relative path to shell script will be correct.
2. use the information provided by `getwd()` to correct your relative path
3. use an absolute path to your shell script as the argument to `system()`

Example:

- Your script is located in `/home/bis/scripts` and `getwd()` returns `/home/bis/R/workspace`.
- The shell script you wish to execute is located in `/home/bis`
- If you attempt to run `system('../scripts/my-script.sh')` within your script it will fail.
- If you attempt to run `system('../../scripts/my-script.sh')` within your script it will succeed.

Hope this helps!